# How to remove version number from a list of programs in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

I want to remove/delete version number from my programs list in notepad++.
How can I do it?

Example:

```
program 1   5.6.3
program 2   3.2.2
program 3   14.2.9
```

I want it like this:

```
Program 1
Program 2
Program 3
```

Answer (score 1):

#### I want to remove/delete version number from my programs

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `(program \d).*`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Disable ". matches newline"
- Click "Replace All"

[image]

**Before**:

```
program 1   5.6.3
program 2   3.2.2
program 3   14.2.9
```

**After**:

```
program 1
program 2
program 3
```

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: It works thank you very much. But can you explain how it works, please?

Comment: @Rachid Please read the further reading links if you want to learn how regular expressions work.

Comment: oh! sorry, I didn't see it.

Comment: @Rachid In the Find portion, `(program \d)` matches e.g. `program 1` etc. while `.*` matches everything else in the line. The special part to note is the parentheses, which turns that portion into it's own capturing group. The replacement `\1` means to substitute only what is matched by `(program \d)` (the first capture group).

Answer (score 0):

For a small number of versions the fastest way is the column selection mode:

Press and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Then select the version block by moving the mouse to the `x` (see next section), press and hold the left mouse button, move the mouse to the `y` and release the left mouse button and the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. Now press the <kbd>Del</kbd> key and the versions are gone.

```
           x 
program 1   5.6.3
program 2   3.2.2
program 3   14.2.9
                  y
```

Comment: How do you do when the program names have very different length? `thisIsMyProgram 1.0.0` and `go 2.3.4`

Comment: @Toto In the question the schema was quite clear that there are visible fixed-size columns. As I said this way is only applicable in simple situations as shown in the question. For variable size columns that are just separated by comma, spaces or whatsoever the the regex way as presented by DavidPostill is the preferred way.